# Powershell. Writing out lines based on string within the file

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to export all lines from within a text file where part of the line matches a certain string. The string is actually the first 4 bytes of the file and I'd like to keep the command to only checking those bytes; not the entire row. I want to write the entire row. How would I go about this?

I am using Windows only and don't have the option to use many other tools that might do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what have you tried ? Is a console application also applicable in your case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to perform a simple "grep"? Then try this

```
select-string .\test.txt -pattern "\Athat" | foreach {$_.Line}
```

or this (very similar regex), also writes to an outfile

```
select-string .\test.txt -pattern "^that" | foreach {$_.Line} | out-file -filepath out.txt
```

This assumes that you want to search for a 4-byte string "that" at the beginning of the  string , or beginning of the line, respectively.

Comment: That second one liner works great. I've just started using Powershell and it's proving really handy. Is there a way to do this while specifying a value elsewhere on the row? E.g. byte 150 to 152 = 127.

Please let me know if this should be asked separately.

Comment: There might be a better way, but you could try something like:

`select-string .\test.txt -pattern "^.{149}$([char]127){3}" | foreach {$_.Line}  | out-file -filepath out.txt` That'll skip the first 149 characters, and then looks for 3 char 127s.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following Powershell function should work for you:

```
function Get-Lines {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$filename,
        [string]$prefix
    )

    if( Test-Path -Path $filename -PathType Leaf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {
        # filename exists, and is a file
        $lines = Get-Content $filename
        foreach ( $line in $lines ) {
            if ( $line -like "$prefix*" ) {
                $line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, assuming you save it as get-lines.ps1, you would load the function into memory with:

```
. .\get-lines.ps1
```

and then to use it, you could search for all lines starting with "DATA" with something like:

```
get-lines -filename C:\Files\Datafile\testfile.dat -prefix "DATA"
```

If you need to save it to another file for viewing later, you could do something like:

```
get-lines -filename C:\Files\Datafile\testfile.dat -prefix "DATA" | out-file -FilePath results.txt
```

Or, if I were more awake, you could ignore the script above, use a simpler solution such as the following one-liner:

```
get-content -path C:\Files\Datafile\testfile.dat | select-string -Pattern "^DATA"
```

Which just uses the ^ regex character to make sure it's only looking for "DATA" at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the lines from c:\somedir\somefile.txt that begin with 'abcd' :

```
(get-content c:\somedir\somefile.txt) -like 'abcd*'
```

provided c:\somedir\somefile.txt  is not an unusually large (hundreds of MB) file.  For that situation:

```
get-content c:\somedir\somefile.txt -readcount 1000 |
 foreach {$_ -like 'abcd*'}
```